# jQuery - Drag and drop - Get DROP left and top position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know where the user drops the element. How do I echo both the .left and .top position on drop?

```
<div id="Draggable" style="position: fixed;">
<img src="images/door1.jpg" id="door">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( init );

function init() {
$('#Draggable').draggable();
$('body').droppable( {
drop: function(event, ui){
// ECHO POSITION
}
} );
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ui.position` which will gives `{ top, left }` relative to the offset element. inside drop callback. `ui.offset` is also there which again gives the same `{ top, left }` relative to the page.

```
function init() {
   $('#Draggable').draggable();
   $('body').droppable( {
     drop: function(event, ui){
        // ECHO POSITION
        alert(ui.position.top);
        alert(ui.position.left);

      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the X and Y coordinates from the `event` parameter:

```
event.pageX
event.pageY
```

These coordinates are from the top and left of the screen, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`$(ui.item)` Will give you access to current `draggable`.